# Laravel proper permissions

Tags: laravel, nginx, php-7

I just tried to change my Laravel project to run on Nginx instead of Apache and can't get the right permissions. Don't really know what to try next. Currently here they are:
[image]

I even gave the 777 permission to the storage folder, but nothing works. I have an admin panel on a blog which always keeps throwing

```
ErrorException in File.php line 190:
chmod(): Operation not permitted
```

Would really appreciate any help.

I am using Nginx, PHP 7.0, MySQL. The website is written using the Laravel framework.

Comment: how about sub-folder's permission of `storage` ?

Comment: which file is this `ErrorException in File.php line 190` ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to review your answers I will do so today in evening :)

Comment: Unfortunately none of the answers helped, I still get "chmod(): Operation not permitted" if I try to access the admin panel. It maybe connected to the fact that I use Auth there.

Comment: Permissions in sub-folders are same as their parent folders.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it with giving the www-data the owners place like sudo chown -R www-data /Laravel/Pblog :D But now I can't edit anything, because I am not the owner :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will work, as`777` is a security risk

```
 sudo chmod -R o+w storage/

 sudo chmod -R 775 storage/
```

Answer (score 12):

First, check the user assigned in Nginx www conf file  `/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
User may be `www-data` or `_www` or any other.

Then change the ownership of the project folder as

`sudo chown $USER:www-data -R ~/Laravel/PBlog/`

Then Change the file permissions as

`sudo chmod u=+srwX,g=+srX,o=rX -R ~/Laravel/PBlog/`

`s` flag means, any file/folder added/created inside the folder will take same permission.

Comment: I am having ```user = nobody
group = nobody```  what should be chown command for me?

Comment: you can add user and group. 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user

Comment: check https://serverfault.com/questions/534497/why-do-nginx-process-run-with-user-nobody

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you bootstrapped your project, there is already a 775 flag on the storage folder usually, another easy fix, is to add your web server user to your group using `usermod` with the `-aG` options :

`usermod -aG $USER www-data`

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way I found to fix it:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage bootstrap/cache
```